# Script to concatenate columns and remove leading/trailing delimiter

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, relational-database

I have a table like this and I want to return concatenated strings where the column values are in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '99'). Plus the values will be delimited by a ';'. So row 1 will be 01;04, row 3 will be 01;02;03;04 and row 5 will simply be 01. All leading/trailing ; should be removed. What script would do this successfully?

```
R_NOT_CUR   R_NOT_CUR_2 R_NOT_CUR_3 R_NOT_CUR_4
01          NULL        04          NULL
98          56          45          22
01          02          03          04
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
01          NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) / [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx). Something like this.

```
SELECT STUFF(
     COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR,'')
     + COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_2,'')
     + COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_3,'')
     + COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_4,''),1,1,'')
FROM YourTable
```

Stuff will remove the first occurrence of `;`

Comment: I updated your script slightly with a CASE statement in place of R_NOT_CUR, R_NOT_CUR_2, R_NOT_CUR_3, R_NOT_CUR_4 to filter values not <> ('01', '02', '03', '04', '99') and after that it works as required.Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to store integer values in strings but here this should work. Try it out and let me know:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (R_NOT_CUR VARCHAR(10),R_NOT_CUR_2 VARCHAR(10),R_NOT_CUR_3 VARCHAR(10),R_NOT_CUR_4 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('01',NULL,'04',NULL),
        ('98','56','45','22'),
        ('01','02','03','04'),
        (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        ('01',NULL,NULL,NULL);

WITH CTE_row_id
AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) row_id, --identifies each row
            R_NOT_CUR,
            R_NOT_CUR_2,
            R_NOT_CUR_3,
            R_NOT_CUR_4
    FROM @yourTable
),
CTE_unpivot --puts all values in one column so your can apply your where logic
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE_row_id
    UNPIVOT
    (
        val FOR col IN (R_NOT_CUR,R_NOT_CUR_2,R_NOT_CUR_3,R_NOT_CUR_4)
    ) unpvt
    WHERE val IN ('01','02','03','04','99')
)

SELECT  STUFF(
            COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR,'')   +
            COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_2,'') +
            COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_3,'') + 
            COALESCE(';'+R_NOT_CUR_4,'')
        ,1,1,'')
        AS concat_columns
FROM CTE_unpivot
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR col IN(R_NOT_CUR,R_NOT_CUR_2,R_NOT_CUR_3,R_NOT_CUR_4)
) pvt
```

Results:

```
concat_columns
--------------------------------------------
01;04
01;02;03;04
01
```

Comment: Your script works, but maybe I should have added to my question that my sample table was just a small segment of a much larger one so while a common table expression will work it isn't ideal because in my experience a CTE will be too much of a resource hit on the database. But many thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `SUBSTRING` there already is a parameter that allow you to remove character

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT CONCAT('/',p.YourValue)
            FROM YourTable p
            Where p.value2 = YourCondition
            AND pc1.ProfilID = p.ProfilID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 
            2, 1000) [ColonneTitle],
```

Where the value '2' is the position of the beggining of the display, so you can choose the char position where the display will start.

(Sorry for my bad english, hope it help someone :) )